# JavaScript: short array inside object

Tags: javascript, game-physics

I am making an object-coordinate association system using Javascript. One way of storing such information is this:

```
//Case 1
var dog = {
    position:[1,2,3.14],//x,y,angle
    color:"#ff0000",
    name:"dog",
    .
    .
    .
    //and at least a dozen other properties
}
```

However, there is another way

```
//Case 2
var dog = {
    x:1,
    y:1,
    angle:3.14,
    color:"#ff0000",
    name:"dog",
    .
    .
    .
    //and at least a dozen other properties
}
```

Let's say you wanted to increment x, y and the angle by one.

In the former case it looks like this:

```
//Case 1
function increment = function(dog){
    var position = dog.position;
    position[0]++;
    position[1]++;
    position[2]++;
}
increment(dog);
```

In the latter case it looks like this:

```
//Case 2
function increment = function(dog){
    dog.x++;
    dog.y++;
    dog.angle++;
}
increment(dog);
```

Considering that accessing array is slightly faster than accessing objects, which one is faster?

***Edit**
In my program, the object "dog" is likely going to be with dozens of properties. Since object lookup speed decreases by the factor of log(n) of the number of properties, I thought that storing the array in a variable first and calling numbers from there instead of accessing a big object every time you want the value might be faster.
Also, since I will be implementing physics in my program, I will likely have to access (read/write) the value many times.

***Edit 2**
Here is the modified code from the user peresleguine.

```
function makeRandomText() {
  var text = "";
  var alpbet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    text += alpbet.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * alpbet.length));
  return text;
}


let dog1 = {
  position: [1, 2, 3.14]
}

let dog2 = {
  x: 1,
  y: 1,
  angle: 3.14
}

let n = 0;
do {
  let key = makeRandomText();
  let value = String(Math.random);
  dog1[key] = value;
  dog2[key] = value;
  n += 1;
} while (n <= 1000000);//n: the number of extra properties



function increment1(object) {
  const position = object.position;
  position[0] ++;
  position[1] ++;
  position[2] ++;
  // maybe cleaner but not faster
  // position = position.map(item => item + 1)
}

function increment2(object) {
  object.x ++;
  object.y ++;
  object.angle ++;
}


let i = 0;
const t1 = performance.now();

do {
  increment1(dog1);
  i += 1;
} while (i < 30000)

const t2 = performance.now();
console.log("Case 1, array(dog1):", (t2 - t1) + ' milliseconds');

let j = 0;
const t3 = performance.now();

do {
  increment2(dog2);
  j += 1;
} while (j < 30000);

const t4 = performance.now();
console.log("Case 2, object(dog2):", (t4 - t3) + ' milliseconds');
```

When the number of extra properties in object = 1

```
Case 1, array(dog1): 5.000000004656613 milliseconds
Case 2, object(dog2): 7.000000041443855 milliseconds
```

When the number of extra properties in object = 10

```
Case 1, array(dog1): 6.099999998696148 milliseconds
Case 2, object(dog2): 4.400000034365803 milliseconds
```

When the number of extra properties in object = 100

```
Case 1, array(dog1): 6.800000031944364 milliseconds
Case 2, object(dog2): 5.999999993946403 milliseconds
```

When the number of extra properties in object = 1000

```
Case 1, array(dog1): 8.09999997727573 milliseconds
Case 2, object(dog2): 6.099999998696148 milliseconds
```

When the number of extra properties in object = 10000

```
Case 1, array(dog1): 7.799999963026494 milliseconds
Case 2, object(dog2): 5.400000023655593 milliseconds
```

When the number of extra properties in object = 100000

```
Case 1, array(dog1): 4.499999980907887 milliseconds
Case 2, object(dog2): 7.899999967776239 milliseconds
```

When the number of extra properties in object = 1000000

```
Case 1, array(dog1): 4.899999999906868 milliseconds
Case 2, object(dog2): 21.100000012665987 milliseconds
```

The result is unstable, but you can see the time for object spikes up as the number of properties increases to 1000000

Comment: I would say case 2 is faster, because you're not creating a new variable.

Comment: What if the variable was global? Would that change anything?

Comment: I created a jsperf to compare the performance differences: https://jsperf.com/array-vs-object-properties, as you can see 3 object lookups are quicker than a object lookup and 3 array lookups

Comment: Thanks, That helps.

Comment: @dotconnor but your array case has 3 object lookups and 3 array lookups, of course that's slower than 3 object lookups.

Comment: Updated it to include a single object lookup but the results are still the same.

Comment: what is *faster* is always going to be implementation dependent by the browser or JS engine.

Comment: Also, all your tests are creating the function as part of your test, which is generally a no-no when you're really concerned with key-lookups and memory access.

Comment: ***Edit**
In my program, the object "dog" is likely going to be with dozens of properties. Since object lookup speed decreases by the factor of log(n) of the number of properties, I thought that storing the array in a variable first and calling numbers from there instead of accessing a big object every time you want the value might be faster.
Also, since I will be implementing physics in my program, I will likely have to access (read/write) the value many times.

Comment: I figured that object looks slower because of the internal hash table resizing. Does that sound legit?

Answer (score 1):

```js
let dog1 = {
  position: [1, 2, 3.14]
}

let dog2 = {
  x: 1,
  y: 1,
  angle: 3.14
}

function increment1(object) {
  const position = object.position
  position[0] ++
  position[1] ++
  position[2] ++
  // maybe cleaner but not faster
  // object.position = object.position.map(item => item + 1)
}

function increment2(object) {
  object.x ++
  object.y ++
  object.angle ++
}

let i = 0
const t1 = performance.now()

do {
  increment1(dog1)
  i += 1
} while (i < 3000)

const t2 = performance.now()
console.log(dog1, (t2 - t1) + ' milliseconds')

let n = 0
const t3 = performance.now()

do {
  increment2(dog2)
  n += 1
} while (n < 3000)

const t4 = performance.now()
console.log(dog2, (t4 - t3) + ' milliseconds')
```

I've run the above script a few times and incrementing the object seemed faster. I was getting this kind of results for 3000 times iteration:

```
// case 1
{
  "position": [
    3001,
    3002,
    3003.14
  ]
} 0.699999975040555 milliseconds

// case 2
{
  "x": 3001,
  "y": 3001,
  "angle": 3003.14
} 0.2999999560415745 milliseconds
```

Comment: My point was that if you store the array in a variable first, you don't have to go through slow object lookup which slows down by log(n) of the size. Looking up the object every time defeats the purpose.

Comment: @Y.Yoshii I've slightly modified your script, sorry for that, however the result stays the same even if the variable has been assigned. You may play with this code snippet (updated) and check different approaches.

Comment: Thank you for the correction.
I apologize but I forgot to mention that the object that I am working on has at least a dozen properties, or possibly dozens. In that case, I hypothesized that the log(n) delay might be significant enough to compensate for the declaration of a new variable.

Comment: @Y.Yoshii anyway, time can be measured) add real data and check the results

Comment: I modified the code and tested the performance by increasing the number of properties. For 1-100 properties, dog2 seems to be consistently faster, but for more than 100 properties, dog 1 seems to be faster instead.

Comment: 1000 properties is a bit unrealistic tho. I will stick to dog 2 method for now.

Comment: Let me correct the numbers. For less than 10000 properties, dog2 seems to be consistently faster, but for more than 10000 properties, dog 1 seems to be faster instead. I ran it multiple times and confirmed this.

Comment: I added the modified version of your code and different test results to my question.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I just wanted to say it's slower than array lookup. I thought the binary search was implemented in the background of object lookup. That's why I thought the time was O(logn)

Comment: baklazan Where in your link does it say property lookup is O(1)? I can't find it.

Comment: Well, I have done some experiments and concluded that it's not completely O(1) because the amount of lookup time increased as the properties increased.

Comment: Ok. I now understand that objects have O(1) lookup speed because of its internal hash. However, this also means that you need O(n) time to resize the table. My test was flawed in a way.